# What is the difference between sh and ./

Tags: command-line, sh

When given a binary in a terminal, you can launch it via

```
sh myapp
```

or

```
./myapp
```

Are there any other ways to launch the app? Is there any difference between sh and ./ ? What do they denote/stand for?

Comment: Also, you can't launch binaries using `sh myapp`, shell scripts can be run that way.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences between them.

Let's look at the first one:

> sh myapp

It opens `myapp` in `sh`.
The command may not work with binaries as muru said.

Let's look at the second one:

> ./myapp

It tells the shell to open `myapp`. The shell gets the app set as preferred and then sends to the application command to open the app.

I remember that  the `sh` way doesn't require executive rights. (may someone who is sure confirm?)